# Why do some medical insurances only allow their insurees to buy 30 days worth of some pharmaceutical drugs (not a narcotic) at once?

Tags: united-states, health-insurance

I have a 90-day prescription for a pharmaceutical drug (which isn't a narcotic) in the US. By default, my medical insurance only allows me to buy for 30 days, i.e. I'll have to go 3 times to the pharmacy (1 time per month) to buy the entirety of the 90-day prescription. I could call them to try to negotiate getting more pills at once but this made me wonder: Why do some medical insurances only allow their insurees to buy 30 days worth of some pharmaceutical drugs (not a narcotic) at once? Understanding it would help me trying to convince the customer service of my medical insurance.

---

As per [quid](https://money.stackexchange.com/users/22881/quid)'s [answer](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/149026/5656) below, I should have used the term "health plan" instead of "medical insurance".

Comment: You seriously expect someone to be able to explain the American medical system to a European in a way that would make sense to you?

Comment: @littleadv yes. See answer below.

Comment: What exactly is written on the prescription?  Was it 90 days or was it a 30 day supply with up to 3 refills?

Comment: Controlled substances include prescription medications.

Comment: @quid Good point, I don't know, I'll ask the pharmacy.

Comment: @chepner thanks, sorry I got misled by some BS I read. Do the terms "narcotics" cover the kind of prescription medications that is more strictly regulated?

Comment: I would just call a drug that can't be prescribed "illegal". "Narcotic" has a specific medical meaning, but seems (IIRC) to have a broader legal meaning as well.

Comment: @chepner thanks,  I had in mind pharmaceutical drugs that are legal but addictive eg opioids, where I can see a better need to avoid give too much of it at once.

Comment: I suspect the answer is along those lines: the insurance company doesn't want to pay for a 90-day supply if you don't actually need it. Making you go back to refill the prescription every 30 days isn't *that* big an obstacle, but big enough that they probably save some money by people not filling prescriptions they no longer need.

Comment: @chepner thanks, good point indeed, that may explain it for many meds. Though in the med I had in mind, it wouldn't be a reason (but perhaps the Pharmacy Benefits Manager doesn't bother making a difference and by default targets frequent refills in the hope people heal/give up).

Comment: I can easily countenance multiple plausible commercial reasons for this but overall the "why" can only be answered accurately by an administrator of an insurance company and only invites speculation and opinion from anyone else.  In answer to the non-opinion "how can I get 90 day supply" variant question, the plans (multiple insurance companies) I've had over the last decade, 90 day fills are available via a single identified mail order pharmacy.

Comment: @user662852 Thanks, I was hoping to get some insights from someone with a good knowledge of health plans. [quid](https://money.stackexchange.com/users/22881/quid)'s answer is a great step toward understanding these reasons. Good to know about the 90 day fills available via a mail order pharmacy! What do you mean with " single identified"?

Comment: By anecdata, Independence Blue Cross uses FutureScripts.  AmeriHealth uses FutureScripts.  Horizon Blue Cross apparently now has two: "AllianceRx Walgreens Prime" and "PillPack by Amazon Pharmacy".  Cigna uses ExpressScripts; UnitedHealth Group uses OptumRx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I started writing an answer to this and abandoned it because this is such a hot button topic, generally, and I have essentially zero interest in responding to what are sure to be charged comments.  And in-fact this probably doesn't answer the question anyway.

The other answer is generally correct regarding new drug efficacy and maintenance med compliance as a rationale for some health plans to impose 30 day dispensing limits. It's not clear that's actually what you're contending with right now.

You might simply be able to get your doctor to resubmit the script.  *IF* you really want to run this down, I'd call the pharmacy and ask what the order says and what can be done, then I'd call your member services number and ask them what they can see in the system and what can be done.  This could be as simple as your doctor resubmitting the order.

I know some pharmacies offer free shipping, your pharmacy may simply offer to ship the med to you each month.

The following is only because I think some people will find some value in the details that I hope can illuminate some part of the US healthcare industry.  I'm mostly writing this because you repeatedly refer to your health plan as "insurance" as do most other people.  The quote in your answer also assumes the "insurance" is unilaterally imposing this limit because of some cost saving motive to use a captive pharmacy to fulfill via mail-order; this *might* be true (though I doubt it, and this ignores the pharmacy's incentive to charge the dispensing fee three times).

---

At a high level most people "insured" in the US are actually members of their employer's (or union's) self-funded health plan (I forget the industry breakdown but I'm confident large self-funded employers cover more than 50% of non-medicare Americans).  There are three basic components to a health plan, these three components exist whether the plan is fully insured or not, though in fully insured plans the stop-loss carrier and/or PBM may be captive;

- the Third Party Administrator (TPA)
- Stoploss insurance, and a
- Pharmacy Benefits Manager (PBM)

**Third Party Administrator and Stop-loss coverage**

In a self funded situation, the "insurer" indicated on your ID card is actually the third party administrator (TPA) which gives you, the member, access to their doctor/facility network but they are not providing insurance.  The TPA may be the stop-loss coverage provider but not necessarily; stop-loss puts a limit on the employer's exposure per-member.  The stop loss may cover claims once a member has exceeded $100,000 in a year and/or some amount of total claims in a year; these are the "specific" and "aggregate" limits.  The TPA has check writing authority on a checking account owned by your employer.  All of this is to say, what you're referring to as the "insurance" might be simply an administrator contracted by your employer.

**Pharmacy Benefits Manager**

The PBM/Pharmacy benefit, from a member's point of view, is not much different than an in-network doctor; and may be bundled in the TPA relationship.  Simply put, the PBM manages the pharmacy network which is not the same as the doctor/facility networks.  As an example, Cigna recently bought ExpressScripts in a very public merger, ExpressScripts has been a wholly owned subsidiary for a few years but not every Cigna plan uses ExpressScripts, even now and other very large non-Cigna health plans still use ExpressScripts as a PBM.  So while saying that "Cigna owns the mail order pharmacy" could be technically true depending on your plan, it's far from a certainty given the actually very limited facts you've presented.  A similar though reversed transaction would be CVS (which owns Caremark PBM) acquired Aetna; and again, this does not mean that all Aetna plans use the Caremark PBM.

**Self-funded Claims**

In a self-funded situation, your employer literally pays the claims up to the stop-loss amounts.  The insurance component is only the stop-loss which limits your employer's exposure, the network indicated on your ID card is not necessarily the insurer.

**"Fully-insured" Plans**

Even if your plan is fully insured, it's not clear that the insurer owns the PBM or that the PBM owns the mail-order pharmacy.  The pharmacy has an incentive to charge the most it can for a drug and your plan has an incentive to pay the least it can.  Granted the various mergers can blur these incentives.

**Your Issue**

It's not actually clear that your prescription and order to the pharmacy actually says simply 90-day supply of X drug and this limit is being imposed by your health plan.  This could very simply be a case of the pharmacy processing the script as 3x 30 days in order to charge your health plan the dispensing fee three times.  If this isn't as simple as having your doctor resubmit the prescription, then it's possible that the 30-day limit is based on your plan guidelines so the move would be verifying that your health plan is imposing this limit and asking for an override from member services.

Many health plans have a reduced cost mail-order benefit.  Generally, the mail-order benefit gets a 90-day supply of a drug for double the 30-day copay; so 3x the drug for 2x the cost to you.  It's not uncommon, as somewhat indicated by the other answer, that these mail-orders will ship from a pharmacy that's captive to the PBM (like CVS Caremark) but that's not always the case.  You can't chalk this up to "some insurance will only let you get the 90-day supply at their in-house mail order Pharmacy, which saves them money" as it's a drastic oversimplification which conflates the insurer (or TPA) and the PBM and the pharmacies.  It's a huge leap to assume that the insurer (TPA) owns the PBM which owns the pharmacy.  90-day mail order at a lower cost is a common health plan benefit regardless of the ownership structure of the pharmacy and/or the PBM.  But it's not uncommon to have 90-day bottles filled by your local pharmacy.

It's probably worth noting with an illustrative oversimplification; drugs don't have a much different supply chain than frozen pizzas.  There's a drug company, there's manufacturer (copacker), there are wholesalers, there are distributors and there are pharmacies (retailers).  You don't buy drugs or frozen pizzas from the manufacturer, you buy from a retailer.  There is a lot of funny business and agreements in supply chain, go research [slotting fees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slotting_fee) for retail.  While the drug supply chain doesn't really encounter slotting fees it is fraught with very opaque pricing and rebate agreements; every supply chain has its funny business.

Where buying drugs gets complicated is you, the member, want to buy drugs in a manner that will be covered by your health plan.  *But*, your doctor submits an order which you don't see and the pharmacy checks your coverage and fills it in the most advantageous manner for them that your health plan will allow.  The default is for you to be a pretty passive participant to the transaction.  To understand the "problem" you need to know what your doctor submitted to the pharmacy, what options the pharmacy may have or offer, and what your health plan may or may not be limiting.  Everyone calls all of this "the insurance" as though Cigna (picking on Cigna) manufactures drugs, distributes them, and owns the pharmacies.  There is not some single entity involved with a singular shared vertical financial incentive known to everyone except you.  There are really three different spokes here and this might be as simple as a call to your doctor's office to change the order, it might be as simple as asking the pharmacy to fill on a 90-day supply basis or alternatively mail you the 30-day supply, and it might require an override from your health plan.  You might have to run down all three to figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, it’s purely how the prescription was written by the doctor.
For many years, and equally many if not more different insurances, I had never an issue getting 90-day supplies *if I asked the doctor explicitly to write it so* (for some reason, their default seems to be 30 days, and they go back to default every time you forget to ask).

Answer (score -4):

Reddit user [Freepurrs](https://www.reddit.com/user/Freepurrs) wrote this interesting [answer](https://redd.it/sho9dt):

> One reason that insurance gives is that when starting a medication or you have a condition that may require adjustment of medication, a 30 day supply at a time is a good amount to assess efficacy and change the dose if needed. If you are changed to a higher or lower dose, you don’t get refunds for medication that’s been collected and your new dose may not be a multiple of the old dose.
>
> Once you are stable at a dose, some insurance will only let you get the 90 day supply at their in-house mail order Pharmacy, which saves them money.
>
> Another other issue is checking for compliance for some meds. If someone has to pick up their heart meds monthly, it’s easy to catch if they don’t fill their meds for a couple of months. Some insurances send a letter/fax to the prescribing doctor about possible medication non-compliance so they can check in on the patient if needed, or they can check a box that says the patient isn’t on this med anymore and fax it back. Some insurances have an outreach nurse who will call if medication refills haven’t been picked up for a while to check on pts. It’s in the insurance’s best interest if people with chronic conditions are compliant with medication to avoid more costly hospitalizations and treatments.
>
> The final issue is that some drugs and supplies are re-sold by patients at a higher value. This is more common for things like blood testing strips for diabetics. There are companies that will buy and resell your strips and others sell them directly online. Some people might have a prescription for enough strips to test 3x a day for 90 days. Some people will decide to test much less and sell the remaining strips. Restricting the number of strips you can buy at once cuts down on resellers. Also if someone is regularly trying to refill strips early, pharmacists and/or doctors may get a notice. If the patient is testing more often for a reason and is logging their data, the doctor might increase the prescription to 4x daily or consider evaluation for a continuous monitor. But if the patient never has any blood sugar data stored in their machine but is regularly running out of strips and their sugar is in poor control, they may not be using the strips right or they may be selling them.

Comment: I think the "in-house" is the one speculation that makes sense the most to me. But either way - these are speculations. And frankly, this is not really relevant to the topic of this site (I voted to close the question).

Comment: @littleadv Thanks, understanding it would help me trying to convince the customer service of my medical insurance, hence on topic imho

Comment: the topic is "personal finance and money", how's customer service related? :-D Anyway, you asked and answered, not sure why it had to be here...

Comment: @littleadv medical insurance is on topic. I didn't have the answer at the time I posted the question.